# Exponential smoothing - alpha choice with given half-life

Tags: mathematics, moving-average

I have daily data for a year and I would like to perform exponential smoothing on this data:

[image: {s_{t}=\alpha \left[y_{t}+(1-\alpha )y_{t-1}+(1-\alpha )^{2}y_{t-2}+(1-\alpha )^{3}y_{t-3}+\cdots +(1-\alpha )^{t-1}y_{1}\right]+(1-\alpha )^{t}y_{0}}]

I want a half-life of 3 months out of 12. 
What is the formula to find the alpha then?

Thanks for your help